# Different speedups on different machines for same program

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, hpc

I have a dell laptop, i7 5th gen processor(1000MHz) with 4 logical cores and 2 physical cores with 16 GB RAM. I have taken a course on High performance computing, for which I have to draw graphs of speed-up. 
Compared to a Desktop machine(800 MHz) (i5 5th gen and 8GB RAM), having 4 physical and logical cores, for same program, my laptop takes ~3 seconds while on the desktop machine it takes around 12 seconds. Ideally, since the laptop is 1.25 times faster, the time on my laptop should have been around 9 to 10 seconds 
This might not have been the problem if I had got almost similar speedup. But in my laptop, using 4 threads, the speedup is nearly equal to 1.3 and for the same number of cores, on my desktop the speedup is nearly equal to 3.5. 
 If my laptop was fast, then it would have also reflected that property for parallel program, but the parallel program was only ~1.3 times faster. What could have been the reason?

Comment: It could be literally anything. Processor performance **cannot** be measured in MHz.

Comment: I'm quite certain there's no 1000MHz i7 processor, nor there is 800MHz i5. Can you say what models are they exactly?

Comment: Physical cores and logical one aren't the same. For extracting maximum performance out of your OpenMP code, this is usually much better to limit the number of OpenMP threads to the number of physical cores on your machine. Therefore on your laptop, don't use more than 2 threads.

Comment: `speedup` is when you increase the number of tasks in a job. if you run on an other machine, `speedup` is not the appropriate term. `performance` looks more suitable to me